# Unable to remove the structure padding completely - Codeblocks: Cygwin

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

The size of a structure ‘item_header’, which is supposed to be 512 bytes as per the size of the elements, is calculated as 520 bytes (using sizeof).

[image]

I tried to remove the padding, but has only been able to bring down the size to 516 bytes. 
[image]

The two steps I found to remove the padding were:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)         :-  This step reduced the size by 4 bytes
__attribute__ ((packed))     :-  This step had no effect on the structure size
```

How can I bring down the size to 512 instead of 516?

**edit 1: The structure declaration:**

```
struct item_header {
    char    history[256];   /* processing history */
    char    params[128];    /* special processing parameters */
    int32   processdate;    /* processing date */
    int32   datatype;       /* data type: speech, lx, etc */
    int32   subtype;        /* data sub-type: natural, synthetic, etc */
    int32   floating;       /* fixed or floating data */
    int32   datasize;       /* data item size (bytes) */
    int32   framesize;      /* no. items in time frame */
    int32   numframes;      /* no. frames in data */
    int32   length;         /* overall length (bytes) */
    char    comment[20];    /* data set comment */
    int32   windowsize;     /* size of analysis window in samples */
    int32   overlap;        /* size of analysis overlap in samples */
    int32   lxsync;         /* flag :larynx syncronous=1,fixed frame=0 */
    int32   lastposn;       /* last frame position */
    char    spare[40];      /* space for expansion */
    int32   machine;        /* machine code: 0=68000, 1=8086 */
    int32   datapresent;    /* data present 1=yes,0=no */
    double  frameduration;  /* time interval duration (s) */
    double  offset;         /* cumulative time offset */
}
```

Comment: Rearrange the structure so you don't need padding? It's really going to be very hard to help you without knowing that the structure *is* and what it contains, or what the structure is supposed to be for.

Comment: One answer -- I realize this may not be the answer you're looking for -- is that if the reason you're trying to remove the padding is so that you can get the structure to exactly match some externally-imposed layout (perhaps a file format or networking protocol), it's often much easier and more portable in the long run to unpack the data one field at a time.  Trying to define the struct just right, so that you can use `fread` to just read it all at once and have it all magically correct, is appealing, but very hard to get right, as you;re finding.  (And then there's byte order...)

Comment: If you want an answer to this question that isn't a guess or speculation, you need to add the complete structure declaration into your question.

Comment: Do you have pointers in this structure? Are you using ints? Depending on architecture, pointers and ints can have different sizes. To help, please provide the source and destination structures.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, I am trying to match the structure with the layout a library prescribes. The structure size has to be exactly 512 bytes for the code to process an input file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

256 bytes:

```
char    history[256];
```

128 bytes:

```
char    params[128];
```

8 * 4 bytes = 32 bytes:

```
int32   processdate;
int32   datatype;
int32   subtype;
int32   floating;
int32   datasize;
int32   framesize;
int32   numframes;
int32   length;
```

20 bytes:

```
char    comment[20];
```

4 * 4 bytes = 16 bytes:

```
int32   windowsize;
int32   overlap;
int32   lxsync;
int32   lastposn;
```

40 bytes:

```
char    spare[40];
```

2 * 4 bytes = 8 bytes:

```
int32   machine;
int32   datapresent;
```

2 * 8 bytes = 16 bytes:

```
double  frameduration;
double  offset;
```

256 + 128 + 32 + 20 + 16 + 40 + 8 + 16 = **516 bytes total**.

You've got too many fields or something is larger than it needs to be (or the documentation you're relying on is wrong, or...).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. The structure declaration is taken from the library. The documentation (which specifies the 512 byte size) doesn't have one of the int32 variables in it.